# Relation algebra predicate evaluation

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

While using relation algebra **(DBMS)**, what is the order of evaluation of the predicate?

For eg.

`σA = B ^ D > 5(r)`

- Is A = B evaluated first `(left to right)` or D > 5 `(right to left)`?
- Also, is there a precedence table in relation algebra?

Comment: There is no single RA (relational algebra). You need to read the definitions for 'relation' & operators that you were given. What is your textbook name & edition? What is its definition of the formulas you can use in restriction/selection? What is its definition of its language for calling relational operators?

Comment: Are you executing RA? On what platform/what database system? If you're not: it doesn't matter how RA executes a restriction; it matters only that it produces the right answer.

Comment: @philipxy then your answer covers the case: "You need to read the definitions ...". That is, the definitions of which variety of RA; what nesting of operators does it support in restrictions (if any -- Codd 1972 didn't); what's the precedence for those operators in absence of parentheses. The sample restriction in the q doesn't show any ambiguity of parsing. Furthermore I doubt there's any (scare quotes) 'implementation' of RA which supports deeply nested operators in restrictions. Unless the q is actually about SQL: the "(DBMS)" is something of a shibboleth, methinks.

Comment: @AntC Yes, there's no parsing ambiguity & my last comment was misdirected towards binding rather than other aspects of semantics. Anyway, I was trying to say that your first comment seemed to misinterpret the question, which doesn't seem to address implemenation, but only "how RA executes a restriction" only in terms of the given operators & syntax. But I see how your answer addresses the question's possible interest in "implementation" of formulas by operators. PS Re arbitrary formulas, there is (SQL-apologistic) RelaX.

Answer (score 1):

> - Also, is there a precedence table in relation algebra?

Philip is correct to ask which version/which definition of RA you are using.

In Codd's original 1972 RA you couldn't combine conditions with an AND (you've used `^`) like that. You'd have to write that restriction as

`σA = B(r) ∩ σD > 5(r)`

If you're asking these questions because you think RA is some sort of execution engine for SQL: it isn't; in fact the semantics of RA are different to SQL in several important respects.

So if you're really asking about an execution plan for a query in SQL, I would look at the execution plan in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single RA (relational algebra) or associated algebra-oriented query language. What is your textbook/tool name & edition/version? What are its relevant definitions?

Binding tells you how to parse into arguments. When there are no state changes & no undefined names, it doesn't make sense to talk about "evaluated first" or "left to right" between arguments. When names can be undefined then there might be operators that allow defined results despite undefined arguments. Eg C's && (aka CAND aka conditional AND) that is like AND but only evaluates its second argument if the first is false.

An algebra is a collection of values & operators. Many presentations of relational algebras confuse & conflate their relational algebra with their language/notation for writing nested calls to relational algebra operators. Sometimes the language/notation has assignment, which has nothing to do with relational algebra per se.

In relational query languages a restriction/selection formula evaluates to a mapping from a tuple to a boolean. It doesn't evaluate to a boolean. We can reasonably say that the mapping is applied to each tuple in a relation to get a boolean from it.

The standard convention in logic for formulas is that binding gets weaker from parentheses to function calls to AND to OR to IMPLIES.

Many relational algebra-oriented query languages reduce ambiguity by forcing parentheses to be present around relations in calls of some relational operators. Eg Typically the parentheses in notation like `σ A = B AND D > 5 (r)` are obligatory.